# C++: Syntax error C2061: Identifier

Tags: c++, windows

I have a really strange problem.

In my header "compier.h" I have the following prototype:

```
void WriteMap(FILE *outfile,clsMapping &uMap);
```

In the cpp I have declared it like this:

```
void CCompiler::WriteMap(FILE *outfile,clsMapping &uMap)
{
    int iSize = uMap.Content().size();
    fwrite(&iSize,sizeof(int),1,outfile);

    int iOffset=uMap.iOffset;

    fwrite(&iOffset,sizeof(int),1,outfile);

    vector<udtMapping>::iterator it = uMap.Content().begin();
    int n = 0;
    for (;it != uMap.Content().end(); ++it)
    {
        fwrite( &it->ByteStart, sizeof(int), 1, outfile);
        fwrite( &it->ByteCount, sizeof(int), 1, outfile);
    }   
}
```

The compiler tells me 
    "Syntax error C2061: Identifier 'clsMapping'.
And it tells me:

The declaration is not compatible with ""void CCompiler::WriteMap(FILE *outfile,  &uMap)" (declared in line 30 in "m:\app\compiler.h")".

clsMapping is declared in header "structures.h":

```
class clsMapping
{
private:
    vector<udtMapping> m_content;

protected:

public:
    vector<udtMapping> &Content();
    void Add(int i1, int i2);
    int iOffset;
    void FeedFeaturesFromMap(udtFeatures &uFeatures,int uIndex);
};
```

In compiler.h I have stated

```
#include "structures.h"
```

Did I overlook a typo, or is it something more serious?

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Is `clsMapping` a class? Have you definitely declared it in this file or included the declaration?

Comment: Is there nothing more to the error than that?

Comment: **Where** does it report the error? Where is `clsMapping` declared, and how?

Comment: What is `clsMapping`? Have you declared it and included the definition where it is needed?

Comment: is #include before CCompiler?

Comment: You overlooked a typo, what typo is hard to say. *Say* which line has the error, *show* all the code up to that point *in order*. It's not so hard. You don't expect your compiler to compile miscellaneous excerpts from your code, so how can we manage that?

Comment: The line 30 is:  void WriteMap(FILE *outfile,clsMapping &uMap);

Comment: Ah.... I got it. In compiler.h I would also have needed to include "structures.h".

Comment: Good, but you did say 'In compiler.h I have stated #include "structures.h"'.

Comment: Or just declare `class clsMapping;` - if you're just using it as a reference in the compiler class declaration you can get away with just declaring it as a class.

Comment: Yes, I was wrong. I added it to compiler.cpp, but not to compiler.h

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include "structures.h"
```

has to be added to both the cpp and the h file.